# code to get address of last 2 called functions

Tags: linux, assembly, stack

I was trying to get address of the function being called last time without the use of gdb so that i can directly trace the functions being called. I have got the return address but when i am tracing the address of function i am not getting the address of function in below the address of the instruction to be returned. I saw the Intel SDM(Software Development Manual) to check the the instruction opcode(opcode for call given is ec and ff). But on relative address difference i didn't get the address of the functions being called. I matched the content of memory using my function as well as gdb, and they are same.

Please help me figure out the address of last 2 functions being called. 
Thanks in advance.

My code and my gdb debugging results are as follows:

My code is:

```
#include"stdio.h"

void f2()
{
    printf(" in f2: entry point\n");
    unsigned int retaddr=0, ebpr=0, calladdr=0;
    int i=0;
    asm("movl %%ebp, %0": "=r"(ebpr));
    while(i++<2){
        //next statement is fetching the return address from stack
        asm("movl 4(%1), %0": "=r"(retaddr) : "r"(ebpr)  ); // %0 = "=r"(retaddr), '=' means op ; %1 = "r"(ebspr)
        //next statement fetching the return addresss-4 address value
        //this instruction is giving some false result(till now, don't know the reason)
        retaddr-=4;
        asm("movl (%1), %0": "=r"(calladdr) : "r"(retaddr)  );
            printf(" in f2: ebp: 0x%x  \tf1 address is: 0x%x calladdr: 0x%x \n",ebpr,retaddr,calladdr);
        retaddr+=4;
        printf("\n");
        asm("movl -16(%1), %0": "=r"(calladdr) : "r"(retaddr)  );
            printf(" in f2: ebp: 0x%x  \tretaddr: 0x%x calladdr: 0x%x \n",ebpr,retaddr,calladdr);
        asm("movl -12(%1), %0": "=r"(calladdr) : "r"(retaddr)  );
            printf(" in f2: ebp: 0x%x  \tretaddr: 0x%x calladdr: 0x%x \n",ebpr,retaddr,calladdr);
        asm("movl -8(%1), %0": "=r"(calladdr) : "r"(retaddr)  );
            printf(" in f2: ebp: 0x%x  \tretaddr: 0x%x calladdr: 0x%x \n",ebpr,retaddr,calladdr);
        asm("movl -4(%1), %0": "=r"(calladdr) : "r"(retaddr)  );
            printf(" in f2: ebp: 0x%x  \tf1 address is: 0x%x calladdr: 0x%x \n",ebpr,retaddr,calladdr);
        asm("movl (%1), %0": "=r"(calladdr) : "r"(retaddr)  );
            printf(" in f2: ebp: 0x%x  \tretaddr: 0x%x calladdr: 0x%x \n",ebpr,retaddr,calladdr);
        asm("movl 4(%1), %0": "=r"(calladdr) : "r"(retaddr)  );
            printf(" in f2: ebp: 0x%x  \tretaddr: 0x%x calladdr: 0x%x \n",ebpr,retaddr,calladdr);
        asm("movl 8(%1), %0": "=r"(calladdr) : "r"(retaddr)  );
            printf(" in f2: ebp: 0x%x  \tretaddr: 0x%x calladdr: 0x%x \n",ebpr,retaddr,calladdr);
        //this instruction is extracting the called address which is our function's address which was called

        printf("\n");
        asm("movl (%1), %0": "=r"(retaddr) : "r"(ebpr)  );
        ebpr=retaddr;
    }
    printf(" out f2\n");
}

void f1()
{
    printf(" in f1\n");
    f2();
    printf(" out f1\n");
}

void main()
{
    f1();
}
```

My gdb debugging results are:

```
Breakpoint 1, f2 () at toUploadsaveStack02.c:37
37          ebpr=retaddr;
(gdb) disas f1
Dump of assembler code for function f1:
   0x0804860a <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x0804860b <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x0804860d <+3>: sub    $0x18,%esp
   0x08048610 <+6>: movl   $0x804878b,(%esp)
   0x08048617 <+13>:    call   0x8048354 <puts@plt>
   0x0804861c <+18>:    call   0x8048424 <f2>
   0x08048621 <+23>:    movl   $0x8048792,(%esp)
   0x08048628 <+30>:    call   0x8048354 <puts@plt>
   0x0804862d <+35>:    leave  
   0x0804862e <+36>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0804862f <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048630 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048632 <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x08048635 <+6>: call   0x804860a <f1>
   0x0804863a <+11>:    mov    %ebp,%esp
   0x0804863c <+13>:    pop    %ebp
   0x0804863d <+14>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
 in f2: ebp: 0xbffff3b8     f1 address is: 0x8048636 calladdr: 0xffffffd0 

 in f2: ebp: 0xbffff3b8     retaddr: 0x804863a calladdr: 0xc9fffffd 
 in f2: ebp: 0xbffff3b8     retaddr: 0x804863a calladdr: 0xe58955c3 
 in f2: ebp: 0xbffff3b8     retaddr: 0x804863a calladdr: 0xe8f0e483 
 in f2: ebp: 0xbffff3b8     f1 address is: 0x804863a calladdr: 0xffffffd0 
 in f2: ebp: 0xbffff3b8     retaddr: 0x804863a calladdr: 0xc35dec89 
 in f2: ebp: 0xbffff3b8     retaddr: 0x804863a calladdr: 0x89559090 
 in f2: ebp: 0xbffff3b8     retaddr: 0x804863a calladdr: 0x8dc35de5 


Breakpoint 1, f2 () at toUploadsaveStack02.c:37
37          ebpr=retaddr;
(gdb) bt
#0  f2 () at toUploadsaveStack02.c:37
#1  0x08048621 in f1 () at toUploadsaveStack02.c:45
#2  0x0804863a in main () at toUploadsaveStack02.c:51
(gdb) x /9x f1
0x804860a <f1>: 0x83e58955  0x04c718ec  0x04878b24  0xfd38e808
0x804861a <f1+16>:  0x03e8ffff  0xc7fffffe  0x87922404  0x27e80804
0x804862a <f1+32>:  0xc9fffffd
(gdb) x /9x main
0x804862f <main>:   0x83e58955  0xd0e8f0e4  0x89ffffff  0x90c35dec
0x804863f:  0xe5895590  0x748dc35d  0xbc8d0026  0x00000027
0x804864f:  0xe5895500
(gdb)
```

Comment: Generally you can't do that. If you use standard stack frames, you can do that using the `backtrace` function.

Comment: Thanks brother for suggestion.Actually i am trying to in-build a system independent function to get last called 2 functions. So can't use backtrace. My program is also printing the function of backtrace, but i need initial function address. I came to result of geting the last instruction in machine language, now i need it to convert it to function address. 'Call' instruction machine language  value is 'e8' and 'ff' in x86. 'e8' for relative addressing which i am getting here. But function address conversion is not proper in my case, need to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can't do that because you don't know the stack layout of your callers. Assuming they use standard stack frames you can use the `backtrace` function which is more portable, or `backtrace_symbols` if you want symbols. That said if you insist on manually walking the stack, here is an example:

```
#include"stdio.h"

void f2()
{
    puts(" in f2: entry point");
    unsigned long* ebp;
    int i=0;
    asm("movl %%ebp, %0": "=rm"(ebp));
    while(i++<2){
        printf("ret addr: %p instruction: %02x target: %p\n", ebp[1],
            *((unsigned char*)ebp[1]-5),
            *((int*)ebp[1]-1) + ebp[1]);
        ebp=(unsigned long*)*ebp;
    }
    printf(" out f2\n");
}

void f1()
{
    printf(" in f1\n");
    f2();
ret:
    printf(" out f1 at %p\n", &&ret);
}

void main()
{
    printf(" in main. f1=%p f2=%p\n", f1, f2);
    f1();
ret:
    printf(" out main at %p\n", &&ret);
}
```

Sample run:

```
 in main. f1=0x80484df f2=0x804844c
 in f1
 in f2: entry point
ret addr: 0x80484f6 instruction: e8 target: 0x804844c
ret addr: 0x8048536 instruction: e8 target: 0x80484df
 out f2
 out f1 at 0x80484f6
 out main at 0x8048536
```

Comment: Can you please explain: What's the error code being inserted on kernel stack on Segmentation Fault ?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>         //next statement fetching the return addresss-4 address value
>         //this instruction is giving some false result(till now, don't know the reason)
> ```

The principal error here is to assume that the length of the `call` instruction were 4 - in fact, in the `Dump of assembler code for function f1` we see that the `call   0x8048424 <f2>` is 23 - 18 = 5 bytes long. Then from the output line

```
 in f2: ebp: 0xbffff3b8     retaddr: 0x804863a calladdr: 0xe8f0e483
```

which shows the four bytes at `retaddr`-8 we see that the first byte of the `call` instruction (at `retaddr`-5) is `e8`.

In the general case, you would have to account for different opcodes and instruction lengths.

Comment: Can you also explain: What's the error code being inserted on kernel stack for Segmentation Fault ?

Comment: I suggest posting another question for this, because it has little to do with the question here and a new one could attract more possible answerers.